# ALV Tree node events are not fired

Tags: abap, alv

I experience a problem when I use ALV Tree without item selection enabled. In this case I am not able to receive an event for node context menu request.
When I turn item selection on, everything works fine.
I get the events for the context menu request for nodes as well as items, but i don't need item selection enabled for my application.

Here is some code I can share:

```
DATA: g_tree TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_tree.
* create container for alv-tree
DATA: l_tree_container_name(30) TYPE c,
      l_custom_container        TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container.

l_tree_container_name = 'TREE'.

CREATE OBJECT l_custom_container
 EXPORTING
  container_name              = l_tree_container_name.

* create tree control
CREATE OBJECT g_tree
 EXPORTING
  parent                      = l_custom_container
  node_selection_mode         = cl_gui_column_tree=>node_sel_mode_single
  item_selection              = abap_true "WOULD LIKE TO HAVE THIS SET TO FALSE
  no_html_header              = abap_true
  no_toolbar                  = ''.
```

And here I register the events:

```
DATA: lt_events TYPE cntl_simple_events,
      l_event   TYPE cntl_simple_event.

l_event-eventid = cl_gui_column_tree=>eventid_node_context_menu_req.
APPEND l_event TO lt_events.
l_event-eventid = cl_gui_column_tree=>eventid_item_context_menu_req.
APPEND l_event TO lt_events.

CALL METHOD g_tree->set_registered_events
  EXPORTING
    events                    = lt_events
  EXCEPTIONS
    cntl_error                = 1
    cntl_system_error         = 2
    illegal_event_combination = 3.

DATA: l_event_receiver TYPE REF TO tree_event_receiver.
CREATE OBJECT l_event_receiver.

 SET HANDLER l_event_receiver->handle_node_ctmenu_request FOR g_tree.
 SET HANDLER l_event_receiver->handle_node_ctmenu_selected FOR g_tree.
 SET HANDLER l_event_receiver->handle_item_ctmenu_request FOR g_tree.
 SET HANDLER l_event_receiver->handle_item_ctmenu_selected FOR g_tree.
```

And here are my handlers:

```
METHOD handle_node_ctmenu_request.
  CALL METHOD menu->add_function
      EXPORTING
        fcode = 'DELETE_ITEM'
        text  = 'delete'.
ENDMETHOD.
METHOD handle_item_ctmenu_request.
CALL METHOD menu->add_function
      EXPORTING
        fcode = 'DELETE_ITEM'
        text  = 'delete'.
ENDMETHOD.
```

So both methods are working when `item_selection` is set to true. Neither of them is working, when `item_selection` is set to false. However, I would have expected the `handle_node_ctmenu_request` would be fired in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in the interconnection of different types of events in ALV Tree Model.
Official SAP Control Framework [documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/4d/8313ca664314aee10000000a42189c/content.htm?frameset=/en/4d/831605664314aee10000000a42189c/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e8/87b8200b8c4915bdd2c89ef55caedb/plain.htm&node_id=387) states that:

> If you set the parameter item_selection = 'X' when you created the
>   instance, you can also react to the following events:
>   ...
>   ITEM_CONTEXT_MENU_REQUEST
>   ITEM_CONTEXT_MENU_SELECT
>   ...

But, unfortunately, it doesn't state (it is implied, like many else in SAP world) that Control Framework treats item and node events *in pool*.
So, if you register item-related events with disabled `item_selection` parameter, the node-related events *will not work as well*.
In other words, **do not register item-related events**, if you want to achieve reaction to your node-related events, or set this parameter to "Enabled".